# How to copy text from pentadactyl to system clipboard?

Tags: clipboard, pentadactyl

I thought I should be able to copy text like this:

`/` + `text-to-search` + `<ENTER>` to find the beginning of text

`n` as many times as needed to go to desired search result

`i` to go into CARET mode

`v` to go into SELECT mode

`l` or `$` or other navigation keys to select the amount of text I want

`y` to copy selected text

But it does not work. When I then paste into Gedit for example I get the text that was in clipboard before i copied in Pentadactyl.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dactyl-bugs/8DIrdCLWTLM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out in this ticket [here](http://code.google.com/p/dactyl/issues/detail?id=799) that this procedure indeed does copy, but to the default Pentadactyl register (like in Vim). There is also an information how to change the default register:

`:js editor.defaultRegister="+"`

To make this behaviour permanent you can put this command without a colon in `.pentadactylrc`

`js editor.defaultRegister="+"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, have been searching how to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a new feature, but you can simply type `Y` (as opposed to `y`) to copy into the system's clipboard [(see Copying text)](http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/buffer.xhtml).